# Performance: multiple conditional WHERE clauses, or dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem. I have to do a query over a very large table with several filters. These filters aren't mandatory: that is, sometimes the query will have to use a certain filter (say, over ColumnA) and sometimes it won't. These filters are passed as parameters to a stored procedure (for instance, @filterA, for ColumnA) .

Suppose the possible filters are over ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC and ColumnD (and the values to filter them over are @filterA, ..., @filterD). If I don't need to apply a particular filter, the parameters are passed as NULL. Currently, I'm thinking about doing something like this using "conditional" WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM LargeTable
WHERE (@filterA IS NULL OR ColumnA = @filterA)
  AND (@filterB IS NULL OR ColumnB = @filterB)
  AND (@filterC IS NULL OR ColumnC = @filterC)
  AND (@filterD IS NULL OR ColumnD = @filterD)
```

This is one possibility, but I wonder how performant it is, given that I would be applying all those WHERE clauses in every case, and the table is quite large.

Would it be preferable to use a dynamic query, where I'd apply a particular WHERE clause only if I actually *have to* use it? Something like this:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM LargeTable WHERE ';
IF @filterA IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'ColumnA = ', @filterA)
END
IF @filterB IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'AND ColumnB = ', @filterB')
END
IF @filterC IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'AND ColumnC = ', @filterC')
END
IF @filterD IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @query = CONCAT(@query, 'AND ColumnD = ', @filterD')
END

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

What's the better option? How do the WHERE clauses affect performance here when I'm basically doing "WHERE true"? Does the dynamic query carry a performance penalty?

Thanks

Comment: If you have indexes on the columns, then the dynamic SQL is better because it can take advantage of the indexes.

Comment: http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql

Comment: While I left a url for "don't fear", I hate dynamic sql.  It is a slippery slope and it is a maintenance nightmare.  Ultimately, I would setup both, and test them.  Indexes are one thing.  Plan-re-use is another (read the article).  If you end up going with dynamic, make sure you comment why you picked so.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better for performance as a `null` check on a parameter has virtually no impact on performance: `WHERE (@filterA IS NOT NULL AND ColumnA = @filterA) OR (@filterB IS NOT NULL AND ColumnB = @filterB) ....`. Each part would only be evaluated if the parameter is not null so only one sub expression (whole part between parenthesis) would be evaluated in its entirety.

Comment: Benchmark and compare.

Comment: See this article that covers this exact type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Can you use an ORM like Entity Framework? Using LINQ in a language like C#, dynamic queries are combined easily and gracefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the better option?

In your case , I would prefer dynamic SQL.

> How do the `WHERE` clauses affect performance here when I'm basically doing `WHERE true`?

All conditions in your where clause would be evaluated for each and every row irrespective of whether you supply parameters or not.

> Does the dynamic query carry a performance penalty?

If you have indexes on the filtration columns then your dynamic perform better.